# Delete Foreign Constraint in Symfony

Tags: sql-server, symfony

How do I give an error if a record has a foreign constraint in Symfony using add flash. The query could say that if the foreign key id is null then the record can be deleted otherwise if it is associated with a record it cannot be deleted and message if it was deleted successfully.  But the error message is not executing. This is what i have tried:

```
public function DeleteStudentRecord(){

                $query= $this->getDoctrine()->createQueryBuilder('a')
                ->delete('AcmeDemoBundle: Student','a')
                ->innerJoin('AcmeDemoBundle:Programme','c','WITH','a.c=a')
                ->where('b.studentid IS NULL')
                ->getQuery();
                return $query->getResult();   
            }

public function delete(Request $request, $studentid)
    {

        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($studentid);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $entity = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Student')->DeleteStudentRecord();

            if (!$entity) {
                 $this->addFlash('error','ERROR! You cannot delete Student Record');
                 return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('student'));
            }

            $em->remove($entity);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));
    }
```

**changes**

```
public function delete(Request $request, $studentid)
{

    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($studentid);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Student')->DeleteStudentRecord();

         if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to delete student record.');
        }

        $this->addFlash('success','Successfully delete student record');

        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));
}
```

But this doesn't produce the correct results either or that's incorrect.

Comment: Can you post what you have attempt on your own?

Comment: Andrew I added what i tried in the question. Is this achievable?

Comment: Could someone please help, i don't know what else do with this part. Andrew could you help?

Comment: Use try/catch block with your `deleteStudentMethod` to catch any exception that might be thrown. Then if an exception occurs, you can set a user friendly message and do whatever actions you need afterwards. Doctrine has a `ForeignKeyConstraintViolationException` that should be thrown in the case you have.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you mean? Then the query I wrote is fine? Why can't add flash be used is there a problem with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to have a bit more to check if the entity exists and then if it can be deleted.

```
public function delete(Request $request, $studentid) {
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($studentid);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Student')
            ->findBy('studentId', $studentid);

        if (!$entity) {
             $this->addFlash('error',
                'ERROR! Student Record with id: ' . $studentid . ' doesn\'t exist.'
             );
             return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('student'));
        }

        try {
            $em->remove($entity);
            $em->flush();
        // Catch the Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ForeignKeyConstraintViolationException
        } catch(ForeignKeyConstraintViolationException $e) {
            $this->addFlash('error',
                '//Whatever message you want here'
            );

            // Whatever action you want from here.....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe try `ConstraintViolationException` instead of `ForeignKeyConstraintViolationException`

Comment: does this belongs to a particular component

Comment: make sure to have the `use` statement for the Exception: http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.5/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Exception.ConstraintViolationException.html

Comment: This still doesn't work even after adding the use statement.

Comment: Why am I still getting this error i don't understand.

Comment: The query that I wrote that couldn't work. Explain please.

Comment: Going to have to read up on the documentation of symfony and doctrine. I have something similar for my college project that works if a record cannot be deleted due to FK contraint.

Comment: Hey Andrew I'm still forward to your help, the fk constraint is still giving me some problem. Can't seem to find any tutorials to solve such. Please reply

Comment: Did you find a solution for the fk constraint as you said yesterday about having done something similiar

Comment: I wasn't looking for a solution. You should be. I have near exact code  related to try/catch in my final school project that works in preventing 500 server error due to constraint issue. If this doesn't work for you, then need to find another answer that might.

Comment: I am looking for a solution...but nothing seems to be working and you said you did something similiar was just referring to that to see if there's something I missed.

Comment: Can someone assist me with question i tried using a query and try and catch but it doesn't seems to work, is there another way to do this?

Comment: The findby seems to be giving me an issue also tried findbyone but doesn't work either gives me a catchable error.

Comment: The error is not executing but rather gets this error Integrity constraint violation

Comment: Hey Andrew you have helped me before with a question and I'm asking for assistance with another question. Can you please help me out:(